# Remove entire inner dictionary from list which is the value of an entry in outer dictionary, only knowing one entry in the inner dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Using Python, I need to build a function to remove an entire inner dictionary from the list of inner dictionaries, which itself is the value of an entry of an outer dictionary. The function parameters are the entire outer dictionary, the key of the outer dictionary, and the value of one entry in the inner dictionary. The function returns the newly modified outer dictionary. So the function header will be:

`def remove_book(books_dict:dict, book_title: str, book_category: str) -> dict:`

Here is the given outer dictionary:

`test_dict = {'Business': [{'title': 'Antiques Chop', 'author': 'Barbara Allan', 'language': 'English', 'rating': 4.5, 'publisher': ' Kensington Books', 'pages': 240}], 'Fiction': [{'title': Anything, 'author': John Doe, 'language': English, 'rating': 1.1, 'publisher': Penguin Books, 'pages':245}, {'title': 'Life', 'author': 'Ray Dalio', 'language': 'English', 'rating': 4.7, 'publisher': 'S & S', 'pages': 592}]}`

I need to remove this part from the given dictionary:

`{'title': Anything, 'author': John Doe, 'language': English, 'rating': 1.1, 'publisher': Penguin Books, 'pages':245}`

So that the end result is:

`test_dict = {'Business': [{'title': 'Antiques Chop', 'author': 'Barbara Allan', 'language': 'English', 'rating': 4.5, 'publisher': ' Kensington Books', 'pages': 240}], 'Fiction': [{'title': 'Life', 'author': 'Ray Dalio', 'language': 'English', 'rating': 4.7, 'publisher': 'S & S', 'pages': 592}]}`

The catch is that the function shouldn't know the entire inner dictionary to be removed, only knows the book's title and it's category, as per the function header above. It would need to go to the value associated with key book_category in the outer dictionary, then search that value which is a list of inner dictionaries for a certain inner dictionary containing book_title as one of it's values, and remove that entire inner dictionary from the list of inner dictionaries.

Comment: Do you want to return a new outer dict or is it ok to mutate the input dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid mutating the original dict use `copy.deepcopy()`:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def remove_book(books_dict: dict, book_title: str, book_category: str) -> dict:
    result = deepcopy(books_dict)

    for category, books in books_dict.items():
        if category == book_category:
            for book in books:
                if book['title'] == book_title:
                    books.remove(book)

    return result
```

Otherwise, if you don't care about mutating the original dict:

```
def remove_book(books_dict: dict, book_title: str, book_category: str) -> dict:
    for category, books in books_dict.items():
        if category == book_category:
            for book in books:
                if book['title'] == book_title:
                    books.remove(book)
```